# NAT and two bridges

Tags: linux, router, nat, bridge

I have a Debian Squeeze server (as router and host for virtual servers) with two network cards - eth0 for internet, eth1 for local network. I installed KVM, so I created br0 (eth0, vnet0) and br1 (eth1, vnet1). Now I need to setup local network access on this server but it is not working :( What I should do to have internet access from local network (traffic comming on br1)? Everything works ok except the internet access on lan.

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br0 -j MASQUERADE
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

If I don't use bridges, such configuration is working (with eth0 isntead of br0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I set up logging in iptables and there was traffic from br1 to br0. Then I checked tcpdump on br0 and all packets from local network were with local IP address. I checked again iptables, added the same iptables command:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br0 -j MASQUERADE
```

and now it was working... Perhaps I did some other mistake before...

Answer (score 2):

The `MASQUERADE` target is a bit "magic" as it uses the IP set up on the output interface to source-nat the traffic.

You could use the `SNAT` target with the public IP address in parameter :

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br0 --to-source W.X.Y.Z -j SNAT
```

I you want to use the `MASQUERADE` target (if your public IP changes for example), you should put the rule on the interface where the public address is setup, eth0 :

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Thanks but I had an error somewhere else because now it is working :) eth0 doesn't have an IP, so there must be br0 as output interface.